# Data-type implementation for axis-aligned rectangles

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

This is exercise 3.2.1. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Consider the following data-type implementation for axis-aligned
> rectangles, which represents each rectangle with the coordinates of
> its center point and its width and height:
>
> ```
> public class Rectangle
> {
>   private final double x, y;
>   private final double width;
>   private final double height;
>
>   public Rectangle(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
>   {
>       x = x0; y = y0; width = w; height = h;
>   }
>   public double area()
>   {
>       return width*height;
>   }
>   public double perimeter()
>   {
>       /* Compute perimeter. */
>   }
>   public boolean intersects(Rectangle b)
>   {
>       /* Does this rectangle intersects b? */
>   }
>   public boolean contains(Rectangle b)
>   {
>       /* Is b inside this rectangle? */
>   }
>   public void draw(Rectangle b)
>   {
>       /* Draw rectangle on standard drawing. */
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Fill in the code for perimeter(),
> intersects(), and contains(). Note : Consider two rectangles to
> intersect if they share one or more common points (improper
> intersections). For example, a.intersects(a) and a.contains(a) are
> both true.

This is exercise 3.2.2. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Write a test client for Rectangle that takes three command-line
> arguments n, min, and max; generates n random rectangles whose width
> and height are uniformly distributed between min and max in the unit
> square; draws them on standard drawing; and prints their average area
> and perimeter to standard output.

This is exercise 3.2.3. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Add code to your test client from the previous exercise code to
> compute the average number of rectangles that intersect a given
> rectangle.

Here is my program for all the above 3 exercises combined:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private final double x, y;
    private final double width;
    private final double height;

    public Rectangle(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
    {
        x = x0; y = y0; width = w; height = h;
    }   
    public double xCoordinate()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public double yCoordinate()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public double widthOf()
    {
        return width;
    }
    public double heightOf()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public double left()
    {
        return x - width/2;
    }
    public double right()
    {
        return x + width/2;
    }
    public double bottom()
    {
        return y - height/2;
    }
    public double top()
    {
        return y + height/2;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return width*height;
    }
    public double perimeter()
    {
        return 2*width+2*height;
    }
    public boolean contains(Rectangle b)
    {
        if ((x - width/2)  <= (b.left())   &&
            (x + width/2)  >= (b.right())  &&
            (y - height/2) <= (b.bottom()) &&
            (y + height/2) >= (b.top()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle b)
    {
        boolean leftOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond   = (x - width/2)  > b.left()       && (x - width/2)  < b.right();
        boolean rightOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond  = (x + width/2)  > b.left()       && (x + width/2)  < b.right();
        boolean bottomOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond = (y - height/2) > b.bottom()     && (y - height/2) < b.top();
        boolean topOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond    = (y + height/2) > b.bottom()     && (y + height/2) < b.top();
        boolean leftOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst   = b.left()       > (x - width/2)  && b.left()       < (x + width/2);
        boolean rightOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst  = b.right()      > (x - width/2)  && b.right()      < (x + width/2);
        boolean bottomOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst = b.bottom()     > (y - height/2) && b.bottom()     < (y + height/2);
        boolean topOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst    = b.top()        > (y - height/2) && b.top()        < (y + height/2);
        if      ((leftOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond  && bottomOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond) || (leftOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst  && bottomOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst)) return true;
        else if ((rightOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond && bottomOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond) || (rightOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst && bottomOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst)) return true;
        else if ((leftOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond  && topOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond)    || (leftOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst  && topOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst))    return true;
        else if ((rightOfFirstBetweenLeftAndRightOfSecond && topOfFirstBetweenBottomAndTopOfSecond)    || (rightOfSecondBetweenLeftAndRightOfFirst && topOfSecondBetweenBottomAndTopOfFirst))    return true;
        else if (x == b.xCoordinate() && y == b.yCoordinate() && width == b.widthOf() && height == b.heightOf())                                                                                 return true;
        else                                                                                                                                                                                     return false;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        StdDraw.rectangle(x, y, width/2, height/2);
    }
    public static double randomize(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + Math.random()*(b-a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double min = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double max = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(randomize(0.2,0.8),
                                          randomize(0.2,0.8),
                                          randomize(min,max),
                                          randomize(min,max));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            rectangles[i].draw();
        }
        double averageArea = 0;
        double averagePerimeter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            averageArea += rectangles[i].area();
            averagePerimeter += rectangles[i].perimeter();
        }
        System.out.println("Average area = " + averageArea);
        System.out.println("Average perimeter = " + averagePerimeter);
        int[] intersections = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            intersections[i]--;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (rectangles[i].intersects(rectangles[j]))
                {
                    intersections[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        int sumOfIntersections = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sumOfIntersections += intersections[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Average intersections = " + ((int) sumOfIntersections/n));
    }
}
```

[StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book. I checked my program and it works. Here is one instance of it:

Input: 200 0.01 0.1

Output:

Average area = 0.6067956188701565

Average perimeter = 44.41595092011365

Average intersections = 5

[image]

Is there any way that I can improve my program (especially the implementation of `intersects` method)?

Thanks for your attention.

One can find the follow-up to this post in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249442/data-type-implementation-for-axis-aligned-rectangles-using-data-type-implementat).

Comment: For the `intersects()` method, I find it easier to enumerate the cases where the rectangles do not intersect: if the second rectangle lies completely left of the first one (second right edge less than first left edge), it's a miss. Same for "completely above", "right", or "below" the first rectangle. Otherwise they intersect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```java
  private final double x, y;
  private final double width;
  private final double height;

  public Rectangle(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
  {
      x = x0; y = y0; width = w; height = h;
  }
```

That really should be something like this, considering readability and the default Java patterns:

```java
  private final double x;
  private final double y;
  private final double width;
  private final double height;

  public Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
  }
```

Having said that, neither is `b` a good variable name. I understand the constraints of printed media, but the example code wasn't already that good.

---

Now, regarding your implementation. Storing the values for `left`/`right`/etc. might be a nice solution. Also, they should most likely be prefixed with `get`, like `getLeft`.

The contains function could be rewritten to utilize that:

```java
    public boolean contains(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        return getLeft() <= otherRectangle.getLeft()
                && getRight()  >= otherRectangle.getRight()
                && getBottom() <= otherRectangle.getBottom()
                && getTop() >= otherRectangle.getTop();
    }
```

---

`intersects` is quite a mess, I have to say, it can be made much more readable by using a helper function.

```java
private boolean contains(double x, double y) {
    return x >= getLeft() && x <= getRight()
            && y >= getBottom() && y <= getTop();
}

private boolean overlapsHorizontalLine(double xStart, double xEnd, double y) {
    return xStart <= getLeft()
            && xEnd >= getRight()
            && y >= getBottom()
            && y <= getTop();
}

private boolean overlapsVerticalLine(double yStart, double yEnd, double x) {
    return yStart <= getBottom()
            && yEnd >= getTop()
            && x >= getLeft()
            && x <= getRight();
}

public boolean intersects(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
    return contains(otherRectangle.getLeft(), otherRectangle.getTop())
            || contains(otherRectangle.getLeft(), otherRectangle.getBottom())
            || contains(otherRectangle.getRight(), otherRectangle.getTop())
            || contains(otherRectangle.getRight(), otherRectangle.getBottom())
            || overlapsHorizontalLine(otherRectangle.getLeft(), otherRectangle.getRight(), otherRectangle.getBottom())
            || overlapsHorizontalLine(otherRectangle.getLeft(), otherRectangle.getRight(), otherRectangle.getTop())
            || overlapsVerticalLine(otherRectangle.getBottom(), otherRectangle.getTop(), otherRectangle.getLeft())
            || overlapsVerticalLine(otherRectangle.getBottom(), otherRectangle.getTop(), otherRectangle.getRight());
}
```

---

Your `Rectangle` class is doing too much, namely, everything. Ideally `Rectangle` would only contain the data for a single rectangle, and a `Main` class would contain your `main`, `randomize` and do the drawing.

---

Instead of using an array, you could use a `List`:

```java
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfRectangles; counter++) {
    rectangles.add(new Rectangle(...));
}

for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
    draw(rectangle);
}
```

---

You could split your `main` also in different functions, like this:

```java
public static final main(String[] args) {
    List<Rectangle> rectangles = createRectangles(args);
    drawRectangles(rectangles);

    double averageArea = calculateAverageArea(rectangles);
    System.out.println("Average area = " + Double.toString(averageArea));
    
    // And so on...
}
```

If you feel extra fancy, you can create a `Configuration` class which, parses the given arguments into a POJO, which is then used/passed around.

---

Your calculation of the intersections could be simplified by directly summing up the intersections.

Comment: Your implementation of `intersects` assumes that if rectangles intersect then at least one corner is inside the other rectangle, this isn't always true. (imagine a + sign made of 2 rectangles)

Comment: You're right, missed that.

Comment: @potato I've added it, I'm sure there is a better way, but I can't concentrate right now. Feel free to edit it.