# Simplifying data-type implementation for axis-aligned rectangles using data-type implementation for closed intervals

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

This is exercise 3.2.8. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Write a data type `Interval` that implements the following API:
>
> [image]
>
> An interval is defined to be the set of all points on the line greater
> than or equal to min and less than or equal to max.

This is exercise 3.2.10. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Develop an implementation of your [Rectangle API from exercise 3.2.1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249393/data-type-implementation-for-axis-aligned-rectangles)
> that takes advantage of the Interval data type to simplify and clarify
> the code.

And so this post is kind of a follow-up to [my previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249393/data-type-implementation-for-axis-aligned-rectangles).

Here are my programs:

```
public class Interval {
    private final double min;
    private final double max;

    public Interval(double min, double max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
    public double getMin() {
        return min;
    }
    public double getMax() {
        return max;
    }
    public boolean contains(double x) {
        if (x == min) return true;
        else if (x == max) return true;
        else if (x > min && x < max) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean intersects(Interval otherInterval) {
        double otherMin = otherInterval.getMin();
        double otherMax = otherInterval.getMax();
        if (otherMin > min && otherMin < max) return true;
        else if (otherMax > min && otherMax < max) return true;
        else if (min > otherMin && min < otherMax) return true;
        else if (max > otherMin && max < otherMax) return true;
        else if (otherMin == max) return true;
        else if (otherMax == min) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + min + "," + max + "]";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double min1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double max1 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double min2 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        double max2 = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
        Interval interval1 = new Interval(min1, max1);
        Interval interval2 = new Interval(min2, max2);
        System.out.println(interval1.toString());
        System.out.println(interval2.toString());
        System.out.println(interval1.intersects(interval2));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Rectangle {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    private final double width;
    private final double height;

    public Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public double getLeft() {
        return x - width / 2;
    }
    public double getRight() {
        return x + width / 2;
    }
    public double getBottom() {
        return y - height / 2;
    }
    public double getTop() {
        return y + height / 2;
    }
    public double calculateArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
    public double calculatePerimeter() {
        return 2 * width + 2 * height;
    }
    public boolean contains(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        if (getLeft() <= otherRectangle.getLeft() &&
            getRight() >= otherRectangle.getRight() &&
            getBottom() <= otherRectangle.getBottom() &&
            getTop() >= otherRectangle.getTop()) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        Interval leftToRight = new Interval(getLeft(), getRight());
        Interval bottomToTop = new Interval(getBottom(), getTop());
        Interval otherLeftToRight = new Interval(otherRectangle.getLeft(), otherRectangle.getRight());
        Interval otherBottomToTop = new Interval(otherRectangle.getBottom(), otherRectangle.getTop());
        if (leftToRight.intersects(otherLeftToRight) && bottomToTop.intersects(otherBottomToTop)) return true;
        else if (contains(otherRectangle)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.rectangle(x, y, width / 2, height / 2);
    }
    public static double randomize(double a, double b) {
        return a + Math.random() * (b - a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double min = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double max = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(randomize(0.2, 0.8),
                randomize(0.2, 0.8),
                randomize(min, max),
                randomize(min, max));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            rectangles[i].draw();
        }
        double averageArea = 0;
        double averagePerimeter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            averageArea += rectangles[i].calculateArea();
            averagePerimeter += rectangles[i].calculatePerimeter();
        }
        System.out.println("Average area = " + averageArea);
        System.out.println("Average perimeter = " + averagePerimeter);
        int[] intersections = new int[n];
        int sumOfIntersections = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            intersections[i]--;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (rectangles[i].intersects(rectangles[j])) {
                    intersections[i]++;
                }
            }
            sumOfIntersections += intersections[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Average intersections = " + ((int) sumOfIntersections / n));
    }
}
```

And the above `Rectangle` class is an improved version of the previous one. [StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book. I checked my program and it works.

Is there any way that I can improve my programs?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The assignment does not mention `getMin()` and `getMax()` interfaces. I'd rather would not implement them at all; in any case they shall not be public.
- There is no need to special case `x == min` and `x == max` in `Interval.contains`. A single line

  ```
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  ```

  does the job.
- `Interval.intersects` logic is very complicated (and suffers the same special-casing problem). It can be greatly simplified into another single line:

  ```
    return max >= other.min && min <= other.max;
  ```
- I don't see how `Rectangle` takes advantage of `Interval`.

Comment: @Emma No I didn't ( -_* ). I just didn't review the second portion at all - it doesn't comply with the assignment requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Interval simplifies the intersects method within Rectangle (the one I wrote previously without using interval was too complicated).

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh It does not. The assignment calls for `class Rectangle { private final Interval horizontal; private final Interval vertical; .... }` and using the `Interval` methods directly under the hood.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. I cannot thank you enough for elucidating this.